# Count distinct same names

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have table where have over 100k information.

```
ID        FirstName
1           Bob
2           Bob
3           Tom
4           John           
5           John
6           John
..          ....
```

Want procedure which will be count how much names are same, For example it must be like :

```
FirstName      Count
Bob              2
Tom              1
John             3
```

Please help me to write it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very basic SQL example, [group by column + aggregating results](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

```
select
    FirstName, count(*)
from Table1
group by FirstName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select FirstName,Count(FirstName) From TableA group by FirstName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT FirstName, COUNT(*) As Count
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY FirstName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Create Procedure GetCount
as
BEGIN
Select FirstName,Count(*) from tablename group by FirstName 
END
```